Connectors type in power supply channels
What is the name of the connectors used for Channel Output in this power supply? I know some use BNC interfaces, but couldn't find the name of this connection protocol for these channels.


ludicrous - Hi, Where did the image (which you annotated) come from? To comply with the site rule on referencing, details of the original source of copied / adapted material must be provided by you, next to each copied / adapted item. If the original source is online & public, please [edit] the question & add the webpage/PDF name & its link (URL) (e.g. website name + webpage title + its URL). If the source is offline (e.g. book or private intranet) - this obviously doesn't apply here, but just FYI - the site rule linked above explains what details to add at least. TY

Combination banana jack and binding post.  The outer sleeve of the banana jack acts as a nut - you can insert a bare wire under that nut and tighten the nut to secure it.

Banana plugs on the cable. Banana jacks on the device. 4 mm ones to be exact.
